# How do I customize the OS X Menu Bar options in openFrameworks?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, user-interface, openframeworks

Newbie question...  I'm new to xcode and OpenFrameWorks, but I have experience in C++. I'm trying to add a Main Menu File to the project but it doesn't make any modification to the menu already there by default. How I tell xCode to use my MainMenu.xib instead of whatever it's using?
I'm using Xcode 4.2.1 and the example openFramework app downloaded from the webpage. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently (by default in openFrameworks 0.8.0+), openFrameworks is using GLFW for its windowing system on OS X.

GLFW doesn't load xibs/nibs, but sets up menus in the source.  You can see where GLFW sets up the menu bar here:

https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/76afd4172727892286fe5728580021a26d198c49/src/cocoa_window.m#L738

If you would like to modify any aspect of the the Cocoa Window, GLFW offers a window handle, which is accessible in openFrameworks in the following way (this will only work on OS X of course, but native window handles are available for X11 and Windows as well):

```
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

// ...
NSWindow * appWindow = (NSWindow *)ofGetCocoaWindow();
if(appWindow) {
    // make your obj-c calls here
}
```

Also, you may need to make sure you source files are named with the .mm suffix or set up to be interpreted as objective-c++ in the project settings.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks bakercp, brilliant response.. although is a little too complex for what I need-know-understand. I can see from the examples in OF that almost everything is driven by key commands inside the apps. I'm guessing because of what you explained in your answer. I'm looking for some pane / window to configure some conditions and constraints .. I'm going for a gui implementation like the ones in the examples... thanks a lot bro.. Any Idea in how to call/create another window from the OF app?

Comment: currently it is a bit difficult to add additional windows, although you might look at http://ofxAddons.com -- particularly these: https://github.com/underdoeg/ofxFenster https://github.com/whg/ofxNSWindower and anything with the keyword "Cocoa" on that site.  In terms of configuration, a lot of people use the built-in "simple" gui (see the example folder for more) or a gui like https://github.com/rezaali/ofxUI, both of which are XML configurable.

Comment: Excellent!!.. thanks for pointing me in the right direction!.. Cheers!